# How to check if an object contains certain objects in its many to many relationship?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, tortoise-orm

I'm using **Tortoise-ORM** which I believe is based on Django-ORM.

**Let's say that my database looks like this:**

```
class Recipe(Model):
    description = fields.CharField(max_length=1024)
    ingredients = fields.ManyToManyField(model_name="models.Ingredient", on_delete=fields.SET_NULL)


class Ingredient(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Is it possible to query all recipes with ingredients of name "tomato" and "onion" using single built in **filter** method?

**Update #1**

I've tried making it using:
`Recipe.filter(Q(ingredients__name='tomato') & Q(ingredients__name='onion'))`

But it didn't work and the generated raw sql from this statement is invalid.

```
 select "recipe.id", "recipe.description"
 from "recipe"
  left outer join "recipe_ingredient"
    on "recipe.id" = "recipe_ingredient.recipe_id"
  left outer join "ingredient"
    on "recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id" = "ingredient.id"
 where (
  "ingredient.name" = 'tomato'
  and "ingredient.name" = 'potato'
)
```

Comment: Never used it, but maybe `Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients__name__in=['tomato', 'onion'])` if it's close to Django...

Comment: I think that it will fetch recipes that also contain only tomato or only onion, and I'm looking for something that will fetch recipes that contain both onion and tomato

Comment: `Recipe.objects.filter(Q(ingredients__name='tomato') & Q(ingredients__name='onion'))`?

Comment: I will check it, and i will let you know, but i think it didn't also work :D

Comment: It's mostly guessing based on knowing Django's orm, and seeing that Tortoise-ORM had a Q-object in it's sources...

Comment: Hi again, I've been testing your solution and it didn't work, you can find the sql that it produced in the **Update #1**.